# Why isn't there <<<?

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

There is a `>>>` [in Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift), but no `<<<`... Why?

(In fact, I'm not sure any language has it based on comments.)

Comment: There is no <<< (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp)

Comment: @PmanAce um..... there is >>>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When right-shifting the question is what to shift in on the left: shift in 0's, or preserve the sign of the number via [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension)? Sign extension means that if the leftmost bit is a 1, then new bits are 1's as well, preserving the number's sign.

That is why there are two right shift operators: `>>` performs sign extension; `>>>` fills with 0's.

With left shifting the rightmost bit is not a sign bit, so there's no reason to shift in 1's. `<<` is all we need.